# Definition of local upper Lipschitz semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $(M, \text{d})$ be a metric space, $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in M$. Suppose that there exists a constant $L$ such that for all $x \in M$

$$
f(x) - f(x_0) \leq L \cdot \text{d}(x, x_0)
$$

Does this property have a name? I am thinking of "Local upper Lipschitz semicontinuity" but I can't find something similar.

Comment: I don't think there is any more concise description of this property.

Comment: Instead of Lipschitz continuity I would use "calmness", since one point is fixed. And I would definitely remove the "local" part, since you require the property for all $x\in M$. I would thus suggest (global) upper calmness *at* $x_0$ or something like that.